Best way to connect Android and Raspberry Pi 4
I am writing an Android app to communicate with Raspberry Pi 4.  The Pi collects realtime data and send to the phone.  The phone will give string to Pi as command continuously.  They are placed closely (<2m) and connecting to the same Wifi.  The Pi is already connected to one sensor via ble to collect data.  Is it better to use Firebase for communication (all data and command go pass Firebase) or use bluetooth ble or SSH via Wifi considering the stability and latency?
